# Poner una aplicación Django en producción en Apache

Tags: django, linux, apache, debian, unix

He intentado de varias formas poner una aplicación Django en Apache (la app se encuentra en un servidor que tiene **Debian**) pero no lo he podido lograr nada, por eso acudo a ustedes con el fin de poder hallar solución a este problema ya que soy nuevo en esto.

A continuación, les enseño las cosas que realice para que por favor me digan si hay algo que estoy haciendo que no está bien o algo que falta por hacer.

Para poner la aplicación en producción se instaló lo siguiente:

- Apache2 (la versión de este es la 2.2.)
- Wgsi (libapache2-mod-wgsi)
- Python-Mysqldb
- Django
- MySQL-Server-5.5

Luego cree un archivo WSGI (el archivo se llama **`awcontroller.wgsi`**) en la aplicación Django que tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path = ['/var/www/AWController/settings/apache'] + sys.path
sys.path.append('/var/www')
sys.path.append('/var/www/AWController')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'AWController.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Después cree un archivo de configuración en la carpeta `sites-available` de Apache que se llama **awcontroller.conf** con el siguiente contenido:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/AWController/settings/apache/awcontroller.wsgi

ServerName awcontroller.com
Alias /static /var/www/AWController/settings/static/

<Directory /var/www/AWController/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Luego me dirigí al archivo `hosts` (`cd /etc/hosts`) y puse lo siguiente:

```
155.555.55.555 (ip del server)   awcontroller.com
```

Puse el siguiente comando y reinicie el servidor:

```
a2ensite awcontroller.conf
service apache2 reload
service apache2 restart
```

Para finalizar pongo en el navegador **`awcontroller.com`** y me sale esto:

[image: Internal Server error]

Por si acaso, hay un archivo `wsgi.py` en el proyecto Django que tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
"""
WSGI config for awcontroller project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/

"""
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "AWController.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Si pudieras poner el contenido del log de apache, seria mas facil ayudarte con tu problema. Por lo pronto deberias intentar usar el wsgi.py que esta en el proyecto de django.

Answer (score 1):

Bro tengo casi el mismo problema que tu pero la solución tuya creo que sé cual es:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    #Directorio de tu aplicacion    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hosproma/servicios/
    #Directorio de tus static y media files  
    Alias /static/ /var/www/hosproma/servicios/Servicios/static/
    Alias /media/ /var/www/hosproma/servicios/Servicios/media/
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    Alias /servicios /var/www/hosproma/servicios/
    #Directorio del archivo wsgi.py de Django
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/hosproma/servicios/untitled1/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/hosproma/servicios/untitled1>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Files>
    </Directory>


    <Directory  /var/www/hosproma/servicios/Servicios/static>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/hosproma/servicios/Servicios/media>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pyerror.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pyaccess.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Prueba modificando eso a ver, a mi me funciona todo correcto con esa config